# Combine 2 SQL statements to get one answer of 'Yes' OR 1 , which ever is easiest

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently have these 2 statements in my query. How would I combine these to get one answer of 'Yes' (like they had one or the other and if they did then give me a 'Yes OR a 1, I need to be able to count all of the Yes's)

```
AND (ZC_VERB_ORD_MODE_med.VERBAL_MODE_C IN ('118','1','102','101','107')
 OR ZC_VERB_ORD_MODE_proc.VERBAL_MODE_C IN ('118','1','102','101','107'))
```

I only tried what I currently have. I wasn't sure if a CASE statement is needed or not?

```
@startdate as DATE,
@enddate as DATE;
SET @startdate ='2023-02-01'
SET @enddate = '2023-02-02'
 
 SELECT 
 --CLARITY_LOC.LOC_NAME, 
 --CLARITY_DEP.REV_LOC_ID, 
 --CLARITY_LOC.LOC_ID, 
 --CLARITY_DEP.DEPARTMENT_NAME, 
 --ORDER_METRICS.PAT_LOC_ID, 
 --CLARITY_DEP.DEPARTMENT_ID, 
 --ZC_DEP_SPECIALTY.NAME, 
 --CLARITY_DEP.SPECIALTY_DEP_C, 
 --ZC_DEP_SPECIALTY.DEP_SPECIALTY_C, 
 --ORDER_METRICS.ORDERING_PROV_ID, 
  CLARITY_SER.PROV_NAME, 
  CLARITY_SER.PROV_ID,
 --ZC_NOTE_SER.NAME, 
 --CLARITY_SER.PROVIDER_TYPE_C, 
 --ZC_NOTE_SER.SERVICE_TYPE_C, 
 --ZC_ORDER_TYPE.NAME, 
 --ORDER_METRICS.ORDER_TYPE_C, 
 --ZC_ORDER_TYPE.ORDER_TYPE_C, 
 --ORDER_SIGNED_MED.VERBAL_MODE_C, 
 --ORDER_SIGNED_PROC.VERBAL_MODE_C, 
 ZC_VERB_ORD_MODE_med.NAME as VERBAL_MODE_MED,
 --ZC_VERB_ORD_MODE_med.VERBAL_MODE_C, 
 ZC_VERB_ORD_MODE_proc.NAME as VERBAL_MODE_PROC,
 --ZC_VERB_ORD_MODE_proc.VERBAL_MODE_C, 
 ORDER_METRICS.ORDER_DTTM, 
 --ORDER_SIGNED_MED.LINE, 
 --ORDER_SIGNED_PROC.LINE, 
 --ORDER_SIGNED_PROC.SIGNED_TYPE_C, 
 ORDER_METRICS.ORDER_ID, 
 --ORDER_SIGNED_MED.SIGNED_TYPE_C, 
 ORDER_METRICS.DISPLAY_NAME 
 --ORDER_METRICS.ORDER_DESC
 --ZC_LICENSE_DISPLAY.NAME
 
 FROM ORDER_METRICS ORDER_METRICS 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN ORDER_SIGNED_MED ORDER_SIGNED_MED ON ORDER_METRICS.ORDER_ID=ORDER_SIGNED_MED.ORDER_MED_ID 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN ORDER_SIGNED_PROC ORDER_SIGNED_PROC ON ORDER_METRICS.ORDER_ID=ORDER_SIGNED_PROC.ORDER_PROC_ID
 LEFT OUTER JOIN ZC_ORDER_TYPE ZC_ORDER_TYPE ON ORDER_METRICS.ORDER_TYPE_C=ZC_ORDER_TYPE.ORDER_TYPE_C
 LEFT OUTER JOIN CLARITY_DEP CLARITY_DEP ON ORDER_METRICS.PAT_LOC_ID=CLARITY_DEP.DEPARTMENT_ID
 LEFT OUTER JOIN CLARITY_SER CLARITY_SER ON ORDER_METRICS.ORDERING_PROV_ID=CLARITY_SER.PROV_ID
 LEFT OUTER JOIN ZC_VERB_ORD_MODE ZC_VERB_ORD_MODE_proc ON ORDER_SIGNED_PROC.VERBAL_MODE_C=ZC_VERB_ORD_MODE_proc.VERBAL_MODE_C
 LEFT OUTER JOIN ZC_VERB_ORD_MODE ZC_VERB_ORD_MODE_med ON ORDER_SIGNED_MED.VERBAL_MODE_C=ZC_VERB_ORD_MODE_med.VERBAL_MODE_C 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN CLARITY_LOC CLARITY_LOC ON CLARITY_DEP.REV_LOC_ID=CLARITY_LOC.LOC_ID 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN ZC_DEP_SPECIALTY ZC_DEP_SPECIALTY ON CLARITY_DEP.SPECIALTY_DEP_C=ZC_DEP_SPECIALTY.DEP_SPECIALTY_C
 LEFT OUTER JOIN ZC_NOTE_SER ZC_NOTE_SER ON CLARITY_SER.PROVIDER_TYPE_C=ZC_NOTE_SER.SERVICE_TYPE_C 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN CLARITY_SER_2 CLARITY_SER_2 ON CLARITY_SER.PROV_ID=CLARITY_SER_2.PROV_ID 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN ZC_LICENSE_DISPLAY ZC_LICENSE_DISPLAY ON CLARITY_SER_2.CUR_CRED_C=ZC_LICENSE_DISPLAY.LICENSE_DISPLAY_C
 
 WHERE  ORDER_METRICS.ORDER_DTTM>= @startdate AND ORDER_METRICS.ORDER_DTTM<= @enddate 
 AND ((ORDER_SIGNED_MED.LINE IS  NULL  AND ORDER_SIGNED_PROC.LINE IS  NULL ) 
 OR (ORDER_SIGNED_PROC.LINE IS  NULL  AND ORDER_SIGNED_MED.LINE=1) 
 OR (ORDER_SIGNED_MED.LINE IS  NULL  AND ORDER_SIGNED_PROC.LINE=1))
 AND (ZC_VERB_ORD_MODE_med.VERBAL_MODE_C IN ('118','1','102','101','107')
 OR  ZC_VERB_ORD_MODE_proc.VERBAL_MODE_C IN ('118','1','102','101','107'))
 AND  CLARITY_SER.PROV_ID='1862' 
 --AND CLARITY_SER.PROV_ID='1348'
 --AND (CLARITY_SER.PROV_ID='1184' 
 --OR CLARITY_SER.PROV_ID='1348' 
 --OR CLARITY_SER.PROV_ID='1862' 
 --OR CLARITY_SER.PROV_ID='3432' 
 --OR CLARITY_SER.PROV_ID='3823')

 order by CLARITY_SER.PROV_NAME
```

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*.

Comment: A `CASE` expression sounds like what you need? I assume the code shown is in your `WHERE` clause. Please provide a [mre] with sample data, desired results and your full(minimal) query.

Comment: where do I add the query ?

Comment: [edit] your question?

Comment: Do I just copy my code over my initial question ? Keep getting this message:Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

Comment: Well no, follow the instructions, add your code in addition, indent it or use backticks to make it a code block.

Comment: OK, but you also need to take into account the "minimal" part of the MRE i.e. don't post your full, large query, cut it down to the bare minimum required to illustrate the issue you are having.

Comment: And you still haven't shown us sample data nor desired results - so I don't know what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the filter in the where clause and count the "yes" (or 1) as part of your select statement:

```
@startdate as DATE,
@enddate as DATE;
SET @startdate ='2023-02-01'
SET @enddate = '2023-02-02'

SELECT
   CASE 
      WHEN
         ZC_VERB_ORD_MODE_med.VERBAL_MODE_C IN ('118','1','102','101','107')
         OR ZC_VERB_ORD_MODE_proc.VERBAL_MODE_C IN ('118','1','102','101','107')
      THEN 1
      ELSE 0
   END included_in_sets,
CLARITY_SER.PROV_NAME, 
CLARITY_SER.PROV_ID,
...
FROM ORDER_METRICS ORDER_METRICS 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ...
WHERE ...
```

If you use 1 and 0 you can also just simply sum() the values of the rows to get the count().